# Select only some parts of a Json map file

Tags: json

Is there a way to select only some countries of a json file?

For example, [given this json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rveciana/5919944/raw/2fef6be25d39ebeb3bead3933b2c9380497ddff4/nuts2.json) that represents the NUTS 2 subdivisions of the various European countries, I would like to modify it and select only a few countries.
For example, if I wanted only Italy (and its regions) how could I do that?

I looked for sites on the Internet that did this but I didn't find anything, and processing the file manually seems a madness.

Thanks

---

I tried to edit the file manually but there are some problems. 
The file structure is:

```
{
"type": "Topology",
"objects":
{
    "nuts2":
    {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "bbox": [-63.15345500000001, -21.387309500000015, 55.83662850000002, 71.18531800099998],
        "geometries": [          
        {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "properties":
            {
                "nuts_id": "ITC1",
                "name": "Piemonte",
                "population": 4374052
            },
            "id": "ITC1",
            "arcs": [
                [2243, 2244, 2245, -1918, -1908, 2246, -122, -164]
            ]
        },
        ...
        ...
        {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "properties":
            {
                "nuts_id": "ITI4",
                "name": "Lazio",
                "population": 5557276
            },
            "id": "ITI4",
            "arcs": [
                [
                    [-2356, -2359, -2258, -2262, -2268, 2361, -2347],
                    [2362]
                ],
                [
                    [2363]
                ],
                [
                    [2364]
                ],
                [
                    [2365]
                ],
                [
                    [2366]
                ]
            ]
        },
        ]
    }
},
"arcs": [
    [
        ... PROBLEM HERE
    ]
    ],
"transform":
{
    "scale": [0.011900198369836986, 0.009258188568956896],
    "translate": [-63.15345500000001, -21.387309500000015]
}
}
```

I removed the `"geometries"` elements that do not interest me, leaving only the Italian nuts 2.
The problem is the content inside `"arcs"`: the elements are many and hardly recognizable..

Comment: you do it via a program maybe python?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do here is selecting them one by one, because the regions of Italy aren't inside a mother clause that enclouses all of them.

What you can also do if all the Italy regions are together in the Json file is iterate to the first one and exit the loop in the last region.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do what you said but I couldn't do it. I modified the main question with more details. Can you help me?

Comment: So, what is your question now? how to get the arcs value and put it inside or what?

Comment: The question is always the same: I want to have a correct Json file deleting some countries. I was able to "clean" only a piece of file and I don't know how to clean the remaining part.